# Is there some easy way to assign positions to nx.Graph() nodes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

Is there some way, to assign pos value to a nx.Graph(), so that it will be drawn using this value by default when nx.draw() is called?

I want to store graphs in JSON format, and it would really help me if I would not have to store this information separately from the graph.

For what I know it is possible to use add_node() with pos parameter, to add single node at some location, but can I assign positions to nodes already present in Graph?

Answer (score 2):

After some though I realized that nx.set_node_attributes() can be used.
The solution is then something like:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(graph)
nx.set_node_attributes(graph, pos, "pos")
```

And later drawing graph with:

```
nx.draw(graph, pos=nx.get_node_attributes(graph,'pos'))
```

The last thing is I had some difficulties with saving the graph to JSON after adding those attributes, but it was also easily solvable.